# Create table with Current_TimeStamp as UTC EpochTime | Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created table with primary key as current timestamp which does the following query. But i need to get the value of ID_ as `UTC EPOCHTIME` i.e.

`1389006147 (UTC)`

Query to create Table:-

```
 CREATE TABLE [PATIENT NAME] ( 
ID_  INTEGER( 20 )  PRIMARY KEY
                    NOT NULL
                    DEFAULT ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ),
NAME TEXT( 50 ) 
);
```

But running above query gives me ID_ values as `2014-01-06 12:04:59` which i don't need

I want `1389009845` instead of `2014-01-06 12:04:59`

Can anybody please enlightened me on these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by reading through  sqlite.org very carefully.

Following Query gives the `ID_` in UNIXEPOCH TIME AS UTC which was i needed.

```
CREATE TABLE [PATIENT NAME] ( 
ID_  INTEGER( 20 )  PRIMARY KEY
                     NOT NULL
                     DEFAULT ( STRFTIME( '%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )  ),
NAME TEXT( 50 ) 
);
```

Following is the TimeString which can be used to fetch the Current Time Stamp in different Formats

```
%d       day of month: 00
%f       fractional seconds: SS.SSS
%H       hour: 00-24
%j       day of year: 001-366
%J       Julian day number
%m       month: 01-12
%M       minute: 00-59
%s       seconds since 1970-01-01
%S       seconds: 00-59
%w       day of week 0-6 with Sunday==0
%W       week of year: 00-53
%Y       year: 0000-9999
%%       %
```